# Alamofire.upload SwiftLint violation

Tags: swift, alamofire, swiftlint

The code for uploading image with Alamofire triggers a SwiftLint violation. How can it be fixed?

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "profileImage", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: requestURL, method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        if let error = response.error {
                            completionBlock(.failure(error as NSError))
                            return
                        }
                        completionBlock(.success(response))
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    completionBlock(.failure(error as NSError))
                }
            }
```

> Multiple Closures with Trailing Closure Violation: Trailing closure
>   syntax should not be used when passing more than one closure argument.
>   (multiple_closures_with_trailing_closure)

Comment: Unrelated but why pass `UInt64.init()` instead of an actual value such as `0`?

Comment: @rmaddy, Replaced it with 0. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is telling you not to use trailing closure syntax when there is more than one closure parameter.

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
    multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "profileImage", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/jpg")
}, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: requestURL, method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.responseJSON { response in
            if let error = response.error {
                completionBlock(.failure(error as NSError))
                return
            }
            completionBlock(.success(response))
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        completionBlock(.failure(error as NSError))
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(_:to:method:headers:)'

Comment: Did you add the `interceptor` parameter name? I think that’s right after looking at the documentation.

Comment: I've copy pasted your answer

Comment: Check the documentation and verify the name of the last parameter.

Comment: Checked. It was encodingCompletion. Now it works! Updated your answer and checked it as correct. Thank you!